# Uploading Large File to SharePoint with FILESTREAM in the backend

Tags: sharepoint, file-upload, sharepoint-2013, large-files

I have tried everything and anything i could find online. But i am unable to fix the following:

[image]
(Screenshot shows random xls file being uploaded, which was standing at around 400 mb with RBS)

This is what i have tried so far:

1. Increase the maximum limit for Web Parts.
2. Increase the time-out in IIS (From default to 1200)
3. Increase the maximum upload size in the web.config file of the web application.
4. Increase the default chunk size for large files
5. Open the web.config `C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\wss\VirtualDirectories\<Virtual Directory>`

I have officially come to an end and now id like your help. Please help.
Thank You

Comment: Can you share your current code please? Are you using SaveBinaryDirect()?

Comment: @Verthosa this is what i followed https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/bogdang/2014/12/04/install-and-configure-rbs-with-sharepoint-2013-and-sql-server-2012/